# How to mark email as 'done' in Outlook desktop app?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm looking for a visual way to mark email as "done" which means I have already replied to this email. How can I make that? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hover next to the email in the list, look for the flag icon "hint". Click on that to add a flag to mark the email as "to do". You will see a red flag.

Click the flag again to mark as "done" and the flag changes to a large check (tick) mark.

Comment: That was really, really useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the mail you wish to mark and you can use the categorize option to mark it with a colored square. It is also possible to personalize the meaning of each color with a text.

Comment: If I color it using categories. Will it be specifically for this email only or will it color all emails from the same person?

Comment: For selected emails only.